# Can i change to mulitiple server farm from single server farm in sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, minrole

Hi i deployed a sharepoint 2016 single server farm in a windows server 2016 server and after can i change this farm to multiple [image]server farm ? to add front end server role?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes , you can convert MinRole from Signle-Server farm to multiple-server farm , for example ,you can convert it to Front-end role .

1. Remote to this server .
2. Open SharePoint central admin page and click system settings .
3. Click Convert server role in this farm.
4. On the Role Conversion page, in the New Role area, click the drop-down box to select the new server role for this server to ﻿change.
5. Click Apply.

You can also using PowerShell to change the role .

Set-SPServer -Identity  -Role

Therefore, you can add another server in this farm, just make sure another server is on the same version with this one .

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790700(v=office.16).aspx
https://www.computerworld.com/article/3039438/it-management/building-your-sharepoint-server-2016-farm-using-minroles.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You are free to change the role (either via Central Admin or The Management Shell).

I believe you need to change it out of single-role in order to add other servers into the farm.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add it with your current role (single-Server farm).

1. you have to change the server role from single-server to any of above( i would go with custom). You can change it via power shell or [using the central admin](http://krossfarm.com/?p=1129)

   Set-SPServer -Identity  -Role
2. Now you can add as many servers as you want.Make sure new server is on same version level as existing server is. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261752(v=office.16).aspx

Comment: sarwar i have the below scenario: We have a SP 2016 single server farm where SharePoint and SQL are installed in the same machine.

only 1 site collection exists in the farm and due to recent increase in team size, we are facing performance and site availability issues.

I would like to increase the servers in the farm.

What is the best/recommended approach?

Comment: do you want to move the databases to new sql server as well? what other services you are using?

Comment: No, I'm fine having the SQL server in the same machine. Just search is running.

Comment: How many servers you are adding? what will be the role of current server? just DB server or both SharePoint and SQL on it?

Comment: Planning to add 2 more servers. Both with custom role acting as WFE+App+search

Comment: And make the current server as only DB server

Comment: 1) i will change the role of exisitng server to custom. 2) then on two new servers install the SharePoint (same version) 3) run the config wizard on each new server and join it to the farm. 4) once all in farm, you can configure the settings as per your requirement which will do what...5) update the DNA and AAM  and SSL as everything should be point & configured for new WFE 6) Now test 7) if every thing sucessfull then remove the exisitng server (single server) from farm and uninstall sharepoint from it. Now it will be db only server.

Comment: Exactly what i planned. Expect for last step,should i uninstall SP only after removing from farm?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96320/discussion-between-waqas-sarwar-mvp-and-george).